# How does jvm ensure java core libraries safe?

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

Recently I studied the JVM. I know when a `ClassLoader` loads `Class` `java.lang.Object`,
The `ClassLoader` will delegate to a bootstrap `ClassLoader`. What if I change the `java.lang.Object` file in rt.jar? Does the JVM have ways to ensure java core libraries are safe?

Comment: what do you mean by safe?

Comment: If you change a java core class,for example cut the equal() method of java.lang.Object,can JVM detects it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the JVM have ways to ensure java core libraries are safe?

If you intend "safe" to mean "has not been interfered with" think the answer is No.

Besides, it would be futile<sup>*</sup>.  If someone has sufficient access to interfere with (i.e. change) the "rt.jar" file, they could *also* interfere with the `java` executable in order to defeat any checks that it might perform to detect that the "rt.jar" file had been changed.  If the user (or a hacker) has effective control of the machine, all bets are off.

<sup>* - And worse.  Tamper resistance is implemented by signing with the private key of a public/private pair.  If Oracle did this for "rt.jar", then nobody but Oracle would be able to build a properly signed "rt.jar" file.  That would defeat the purpose of making Java open source, and *really, really annoy a lot of people!!*</sup>

(By contrast, when JAR files are downloaded and run in a web browser or using web-start, the JVM / classloader checks that they are properly signed before letting them run.  But there you are checking for interference by a third-party ... etcetera ... not interference by someone with local admin rights.)

---

There is another meaning of "safe"; i.e. that the libraries not contain Java bytecodes that will cause runtime type-safety to be violated.  The answer in that case is Yes.

The JVM verifies the bytecodes loaded to check for things that would violate runtime type-safety, and potentially crash the JVM.  If the code is bad, the `VerifyError` exception is thrown, and the class load operation fails.

Reference:

- The Java Language Environment: [6.3 The Byte Code Verification Process](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/security-136118.html)

Comment: +1 BTW Pre-pending to the bootclasspath allows you to override anything in `rt.jar` without needing to tamper with it. i.e. there is little value in protecting it given there is an even easier way to tamper with the classes in it.

Comment: And if you don't like having to add to the bootclasspath, you can use the `lib/endorsed` directory, or you can use byte code manipulation. ;)

Comment: Coming from someone as distinguished as yourself, I will take that as a complement. ;)

Answer (score 1):

When JVM load class, it will execute follow steps:
1. Load the class file from jar file or classpath(depand on class loader), java.lang.Object is in rt.jar, JVM will find it and load it to method area of JVM.

1. Verify the class file while was loaded by step 1. Class file has its own format(depand on JVM version) , such as privious 4 bytes is 0XCAFEBABE. JVM will throws error when the format class file is not correct. If the format of the java.lang.Object you modified  is not correct. The JVM will not load it.
2. JVM will allocate memory for you Class.
3. JVM will parse symbol link to direct link.
4. Initialize your Class.

Hope to help you. Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the j`ava.lang.Objec`t and if it does not passthe `ByteCode verification process`, then it may throw error. Other wise there is no check enfored by jvm to say it is safe or not